# Extract The Specific parameter value from array

Tags: php

I have a array like this

```
 [0] => Array
          (
             [0] => LBLdss_COLLEsdfCTIONS_RsdfsdEPORT_TITfsdfLE
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Administration] => Array
                        (

                        [bidsflldsf6] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => themes/Care2012/images/Payments
                                [1] => LsdfBL_OPsddfD_BIsfdfsLLING_SsdfdsUMsdfMARY_TITLE
                                [2] => LsdfsdBL_OPDfdsfd_BILfdsLING_dsfdsSUMMARY
                                [3] => ./index.php?module=Rsdfepfdsforts&action=reposfdfdsrtsel&rname=Opdpasfdfypdf
                            )

                        [bilhghjgl_pat_reg] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => themsdfsdes/Casfdfre2aasd012/imasdfges/Pasdymesddfnts
                                [1] => LBL_sdfsPAT_RsdfEG_TsdfITLE
                                [2] => LBL_PdfsdAT_sfdREG_TdsfdITLE_DsdfsETAIL
                                [3] => ./index.php?module=Rexcvpofdsrts&action=reportsel&rname=Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => 
    )
```

Now i need to extract value of rname from this index [3] => ./index.php?module=Rexcvpofdsrts&action=reportsel&rname=Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf (which is Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf in this case)and have to save it
I can try explode function but it is heavy for me since my array size is large
please help in resolving this
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need? Is it "Administration" or "bidsflldsf6" and "bilhghjgl_pat_reg"?

Comment: rname from this index                             [3] => ./index.php?module=Rexcvpofdsrts&action=reportsel&rname=Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a foreach for ciclying the array and formulate a regular expression for extract your param. Like this:

```
foreach($youvar as $text) {
    preg_match('$rname=(.+?)$', $text, $rname[]) 
}
```

After that you can try a print_r on $rname and adapt to you.

Comment: Not extracting the complete value its only extracting the first character

Comment: No. This code must extract the complete value. 
Look on Wikipedia: "Regular Expressions", this must extract all the chars after "rname=".

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
$a = explode("rname=", index[3]);

echo $a[1;]
```

Comment: I didn't need explode function

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
$array = array(
    './index.php?module=Rsdfepfdsforts&action=reposfdfdsrtsel&rname=Opdpasfdfypdf',
    './index.php?module=Rexcvpofdsrts&action=reportsel&rname=Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf',
);

function getRname($str){
    //return null if not found
    preg_match('/rname\=([a-zA-Z]+)($|&)/', $str , $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

foreach($array as $str){
    echo "Rname: " . getRname($str). "<br/>";
}
```

Result

```
Rname: Opdpasfdfypdf
Rname: Pacxvtregcollxcvectionpdf
```

Try it?